# How do I add a rel attribute to the URL of a component link?

Tags: 2009, dwt, tcdl

I just noticed the title of the question has been updated. I'm not sure you understand what i'm looking for. Maybe i was not clear enough.

In a DWT i have the following block of code:

```
 <div class="contactBloc">

                      <legend class="hidden">@@Component.Fields.theme_title@@</legend>

                       <h2>@@Component.Fields.theme_title@@</h2>
                       <div class="fieldset">
                                       <ul id="selectTheme">
                                                       <!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="Component.Fields.theme" -->
                                                       <li><a tridion:href="@@Field.theme_form@@" rel="">@@Field.theme_name@@</a></li>
                                                       <!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->                                                    
                                       </ul>
                                       <span class="clear">&nbsp;</span>
                       </div>
        </div>
```

in the "a" tag above, the href attribute contains for instance "/contact/contact.aspx"

This is how it works right now!

Now, i don't use any "a" tags anymore, i have to use a "input" tag instead. Therefore, i want to display "/contact/contact.aspx" in the "rel" attribute of the "input" tag.

Instead of

```
<a tridion:href="@@Field.theme_form@@" rel="">@@Field.theme_name@@</a>
```

i tried, as you wrote:

```
<input type=""checkbox" tridion:href="@@Field.theme_form@@" tridion:targetattribute="rel">@@Field.theme_name@@</a>
```

But in the code generated, i have no rel and what href contains instead of "/contact/contact.aspx" is just "tcm:XX-XXXX"

Thanks for your help

Comment: Hi Arnaud. You're probably for `tridion:linkAttributes`. See this question from some info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12046332/whats-the-correct-format-for-tcdl-linkattributes and http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/2346/can-we-attach-a-query-string-using-the-sdl-tridion-component-link-resolver

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fast reply. Unfortunately this is the code generated:

<input id="Investor Relations" type="checkbox" tridion:linkattributes="tcm:127-28220">

Comment: it's tridion:targetattribute, see answer below.

Comment: Your input element looks malformed - is that what's in your template verbatim? `type=""checkbox"` - also, not sure if this is necessary but in Nuno's example he includes a dummy `rel` attribute.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to Stack Exchange Arnaud.

[This page](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-3324C14A-13DB-4147-9773-F4B4A924D09D) on SDL Live Content (login required) shows the various options you have for linking.

You can achieve the functionality you want with something like this:

```
<input id="blahblah" rel="something" tridion:href="@@Field.theme.form@@" tridion:targetattribute="rel" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your help:
I tried this : <input tridion:targetattribute="@@Field.theme_form@@"></input>
But the code generate is : tridion:targetattribute="tcm:XX-XXXX" :(

Comment: Nuno says to set `<input tridion:targetattribute="rel" tridion:href="@@Field.theme.form@@"`. Copy/paste carefully please.

Comment: You need to use both tridion:href and tridion:targetattribute="name_of_attribute_to_get_result"

Comment: I just tried what you wrote but it still does not work. no "rel" attribute appears in my input and the href contains "tcm:XX-XXXX".

On the other hand when i write this tridion:href in a "a" tag it works ...